# prove $\cos \left(\alpha \right)+\cos \left(\beta \right)+\cos \left(\gamma \right)$ equals.... if $\alpha +\beta +\gamma =\pi $

Tags: trigonometry

I am looking at the solution of this problem: 
 $$\cos \left(\alpha \right)+\cos \left(\beta \right)+\cos \left(\gamma \right)=4\sin \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)\sin \left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right)\sin \left(\frac{\gamma }{2}\right)$$ and it says this in the solution as the first step: $$\cos \left(\alpha \right)+\cos \left(\beta \right)+\cos \:\left(\gamma \:\right)=2\cos \left(\frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{\alpha -\beta }{2}\right)-2\cos \left(\frac{\alpha \:+\beta \:}{2}\right)^2+1$$

I understand that the $\cos \alpha +\cos \beta=2\cos \left({\frac {\alpha +\beta }{2}}\right)\cos \left({\frac {\alpha -\beta }{2}}\right)$ is used, however how is the $cos \:\left(\gamma \:\right)$ transformed? I assume I should use the $\alpha +\beta +\gamma =\pi $ to replace $\gamma$ but can't seem to figure it out?
Any help is very much appreciated. x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$ \cos \gamma = \cos(\pi-(\alpha+\beta)) = -\cos(\alpha+\beta) = -2 \cos^2\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2} + 1$$
Two formulas are used here:
$$ \cos (\pi-x) = -\cos x $$
and
$$ \cos (2x) = 2 \cos^2 x -1$$
Later you'll also need
$$ \cos(\frac{\pi}{2} -x) = \sin x $$

Comment: Thank you so much Adam! I did come to the cos(π−x)=−cosx at one point, however was so lost about what to do next, thank you for the other formula especially and for additional help! Not all heroes wear capes. xx

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a $+1$:$$\begin{align}\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma&=2\cos\tfrac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\cos\tfrac{\alpha-\beta}{2}-\cos(\alpha+\beta)\\&=2\cos\tfrac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\left(\cos\tfrac{\alpha-\beta}{2}-\cos\tfrac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)+1\\&=2\sin\tfrac{\gamma}{2}2\sin\tfrac{\alpha}{2}\sin\tfrac{\beta}{2}+1.\end{align}$$